# How to identify which OS is running at remote host?

Tags: linux, windows

I'm unable to identify which OS is running at remote host,how can identify the remote host OS ?

Comment: http://nmap.org/book/man-os-detection.html

Comment: just look at it hard with xray-eyes. seriously: you should at least state the means by what you want to identify "the remote host OS".

Comment: And what's about more info? Does remote host have opened ports with services running?

Comment: actually I'm junior system admin and i don't have permission to access remote server , yup there are several services are running Like CSVN .

Comment: If you are a junior sysadmin, either ask someone your senior or accept that you aren't supposed to know for whatever reason. Don't try to go behind peoples' backs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use nmap. It isn't precise, but it can give you a clue. Or you can use a simple "ping" and look for the TTL.

```
TTL=64 = *nix - the hop count so if your getting 61 then there are 3 hops and its a *nix device. Most likely Linux.
TTL=128 = Windows - again if the TTL is 127 then the hop is 1 and its a Windows box.
TTL=254 = Solaris/AIX - again if the TTL is 250 then the hop count is 4 and its a Solaris box.
```

And with NMAP:

```
# sudo nmap -O xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Comment: What does TTL have to do with the OS?